# Name for symmetric functions, $f(x, y)=g(x) h(y)+h(x) g(y)$.

Tags: functions, terminology

I was playing around with some ideas and thinking that this function
$$f(x, y)=x \sqrt y+y \sqrt x $$
looked like it might be fun to explore.

But then I considered looking at the set of functions with the same structure.
$$f(x, y)=g(x) h(y)+h(x) g(y)$$
and this might be even more interesting.

Of course, this idea could be extended to functions
in 3 variables like
$$ f(x, y, z)=xy+yz+zx $$

If there was a name for this type of function, then that would give me a lead and help me look up what other people have found out.  If this type of function does have a name.

Or maybe there are some interesting places to start exploring?

---

I think the extension to three variables that I would use would use a cycle rule...
$$f(x, y, z)=g(x)h(y)j(z)+h(x)j(y)g(z)+j(x)h(y)g(z) $$

Comment: Seems related to symmetric kernels.

Comment: Do you mean a name that covers all three examples, but isn’t just “symmetric function”? Your third example is an elementary symmetric function.

Comment: I think the word "separable"is sometimes used for this

Comment: I should have thought that 'symmetric function' would be the name to look at.  Although what I have is a subset, since f(x,y)=x^y+y^x wouldn't be part of the set that I defined.

Comment: I don't know a name for that set. But it looks interesting and you may want to clarify. Is $f(w,x,y,z)=wx\sqrt{y}+wy\sqrt{x}+xy\sqrt{w}$ part of the set or just 
$g(w,x,y,z)=w\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt{w}+\dots+x\sqrt{y}+y\sqrt{x}\,?$ (The square-root is just an example to simplify notation. You can play that game with any collection of univariate functions $a(w),b(x),c(y),d(z)\,.$)

Comment: I meant my last comment in a straightforward way.

Comment: _I_ would describe what you have as "a symmetrization of a product of univariate (1-ary) functions". But I don't think that will help you in searching.